# using apply to compare rows in the same dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using python 3.

Here are some sample rows from my original dataframe (output_df)

[image]

I am looking to write a function which does the following:

For a single given UNITID - it should suggest all similar programs from other institutions (with different UNITID) based on two criteria:

**1 -** ignoring the decimal, first 4 digits in the “CIPCODE” column should be same, but rest of the digits HAVE to be different. for example for the first row shown above, 51.0102 is a possible match

**2 -** same value in “type” column

Here is my code so far:

#output_df contains my original dataframe

```
output_df["CIPCODE"] = output_df["CIPCODE"].astype(str).str.zfill(7) #to standardize formatting
```

The function

```
def find_similar_programs(row, df):
    cipcode = str(row['CIPCODE']).replace('.','')  # Extract the CIPCODE without the decimal part
    program_type = row['type']

    # Filter the dataframe based on the criteria
    similar_programs = df[
        (df['CIPCODE'].astype(str).str.startswith(cipcode[0:4])) &  
        (~ (df['CIPCODE'].astype(str).str.startswith(cipcode[0:6]))) & 
        (df['type'] == program_type)  # Matches the program type
    ]

    return similar_programs
```

I am not sure how to call this using the apply function within the context of the problem statement described above. I am also not sure if I have implemented the filtering correctly within the function, although the logic looked good to me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please add a few more rows to the above data, as well as the filter criteria? What does that look like? is it a row? is it a separate data frame? is it a specific value or list of values or an object?

Comment: the filter function is just my attempt to generate matches according to the criteria in the problem statement

Comment: I just have one dataframe (output_df) shown above

Comment: can you add more rows? what does your expected output look like? can you also add that?

Comment: I have added more rows. So basically, for all rows of a given UNITID, I need to find matching rows from other institutions (different UNITID) based on the criteria mentioned

Comment: Hey, please don;t add data as screenshots. Its impossible to replicate for anyone. Please use the previous method you had used to share data, and just add a few more rows. Also as I had requested before, please also add the expected output data for others to understand what your end goal is.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion on how you can achieve your desired result:

```py
import pandas as pd


data = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [177986, "Logan University", "Chiropractic", 51.0101,
         "Doctor's degree - professional practice"],
        [177986, "Logan University", "Natural Sciences", 30.1801, "Bachelor's degree"],
        [177987, "MIT University", "Natural Sciences", 30.1891, "Bachelor's degree"],
    ], columns=['NITID', 'institution_name', 'program_name', 'CIPCODE', 'type']
)

data['CIPCODE'] = data['CIPCODE'].astype(str).str.zfill(7)
data['CIPCODE_group'] = data['CIPCODE'].str.replace(".", "").str[:4]
data['CIPCODE_decimal'] = data['CIPCODE'].str.replace(".", "").str[4:]


def find_similar_programs(row: pd.Series, df: pd.DataFrame) -> list:
    """Find similar programs to the one currently being processed.

    This function applies the following filters, to find similar programs:

    - Select rows with the same CIPCODE group as the current row.
    - Select rows with the same type as the current row.
    - Select rows with different NITID than the current row.
    - Select rows with different CIPCODE decimal than the current row.

    Parameters
    ----------
    row : pd.Series
        Row from the dataframe being processed.
    df : pd.DataFrame
        Pandas Dataframe containing all the available courses.

    Returns
    -------
    list
        List of "CIPCODE" codes from similar programs to the one currently
        being processed. If no similar programs are found, then an empty list
        is returned.

    Notes
    -----
    - This function was written to be used with `pandas.DataFrame.apply`.
    - To retrieve the rest of the columns from similar programs found, filter
      the dataframe using the returned list of "CIPCODE" codes.
      Here's an example:

      .. code-block:: python

        similar_programs = find_similar_programs(row, df)
        df[df['CIPCODE'].isin(similar_programs[0])]

      The above example will return all programs similar to the first course
      from the `df` dataframe.
    """
    return df[
        (df['CIPCODE_group'] == row['CIPCODE_group'])
        & (df['CIPCODE_decimal'] != row['CIPCODE_decimal'])
        & (df['type'] == row['type'])
        & (df['NITID'] != row['NITID'])
    ]['CIPCODE'].unique().tolist()


# You can use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` by specifying the function you wish to
# apply to each row. when the function requires extra parameters other than the
# row itself, you can pass them as either positional or keyword arguments.
# axis = 1 means `apply` the function to each row
# NOTE: `axis` only needs to be specified, when using `apply` on a dataframe,
#       and you want to apply function row-wise.
similar_programs = data.apply(find_similar_programs, df = data, axis = 1)

# Could also be used like this:
similar_programs = data.apply(find_similar_programs, args=(data,), axis = 1)

# Or like this:
similar_programs = data.apply(lambda row: find_similar_programs(row, data), axis = 1)

# The returned lists of similar programs can also be added to the dataframe
# as a new column:
data['similar_programs'] = similar_programs
data
# Output:
#
#     NITID  ...  CIPCODE                                     type CIPCODE_group CIPCODE_decimal similar_programs
# 0  177986  ...  51.0101  Doctor's degree - professional practice          5101              01               []
# 1  177986  ...  30.1801                        Bachelor's degree          3018              01        [30.1891]
# 2  177987  ...  30.1891                        Bachelor's degree          3018              91        [30.1801]
```

### Considerations

In the code above, I assumed that all programs have unique "CIPCODE" values. Based on this assumption, I've written the `find_similar_programs` function to return a list of unique "CIPCODE" values from the similar programs found.
If this assumption I made is false, you can replace `['CIPCODE'].unique().tolist()` with `.index.to_list()` in the final portion of the `find_similar_programs` function.

Also, are you sure you want to standardize the "CIPCODE" values using `pandas.Series.str.zfill`? `zfill` will add leading zeroes to each string that has a length smaller than the specified width. This might cause some problems with your first filter rule ("first 4 digits in the “CIPCODE” column should be same"). Additionally, If some values have more than 7 characters, `zfill` will leave them unmodified. Here's an example:

```py
pd.Series([30.1891, 30.18, 30.1891212]).astype(str).str.zfill(7)
# Output:
#
# 0       30.1891
# 1       0030.18
# 2    30.1891212
# dtype: object
```

The safest solution would be to filter out "CIPCODE" values that have a length different than 7 characters and treat them manually.

Comment: thanks so much! I have accepted your answer

Comment: I hope you live a happy and blessed life

Comment: I'm having some issues with this same problem, can you please take a look, I'd be so grateful - https://stackoverflow.com/q/76373257/19903400