# Filtering dataframe using apply

Tags: python, pandas

My original dataset has the following columns along with dummy values shown:

```
UNITID : 100654
institution_name : Harvard
program_name : Medicine
CIPCODE : 52.0203
type : Bachelor's
```

Here is some sample data (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wPszchjVgn18SCp4TOH9gPklCK9CH3tPn-GHJUGjnRU/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is what I am trying to do:

For each of the rows of this dataset which are relevant to a certain single UNITID (I will refer to this as data_subset in the code below), I am trying to get similar rows from the original dataset based on the following conditions:

```
The first four digits of CIPCODE should be same
The rest of the digits of CIPCODE should be different
The "type" should be same
The UNITID should be different
```

Here is my code:

```
#data is my original dataframe

data['CIPCODE'] = data['CIPCODE'].astype(str).str.zfill(7)
data['CIPCODE_group'] = data['CIPCODE'].str.replace(".", "").str[:4]
data['CIPCODE_decimal'] = data['CIPCODE'].str.replace(".", "").str[4:]

def find_similar_programs(row: pd.Series, df: pd.DataFrame):
  
    return df[
        (df['CIPCODE_group'] == row['CIPCODE_group'])
        & (df['CIPCODE_decimal'] != row['CIPCODE_decimal'])
        & (df['type'] == row['type'])
        & (df['UNITID'] != row['UNITID'])]

data_subset=data[data['UNITID']==166027]

similar_programs = data_subset.apply(find_similar_programs, df = data, axis = 1)
```

The problem is that I am getting an output which is like this which is not the required result:

```
    92653            UNITID                                ...
92654    Empty DataFrame
Columns: [UNITID, institution_...
92655            UNITID                                ...
92656            UNITID                                ...
92657    Empty DataFrame
Columns: [UNITID, institution_...
92658            UNITID                   institution_n...
92659            UNITID                                ...
92660    Empty DataFrame
Columns: [UNITID, institution_...
92661            UNITID                                ...
92662    Empty DataFrame
Columns: [UNITID, institution_...
92663            UNITID                                ...
92664    Empty DataFrame
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal executable code, I mean with the input dataframe as row data example dummy.

Comment: stackoverflow has made pasting a nightmare, everytime I paste, it turns it into an image

Comment: Here is some sample data  - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wPszchjVgn18SCp4TOH9gPklCK9CH3tPn-GHJUGjnRU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you really only want the result for one `UNITID` then you could just add `similar_programs = pd.concat(similar_programs.to_list())` to the end of your code.

Comment: @Timus if I do that, for the code in the question above, it should scan the entire dataset BUT generate matches for only UNITID=166027 right?

Comment: @Timus thanks so much for helping, may you have a happy and blessed life!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: Using the helpful suggestion from Timus in the comments, it is better to use a regular merge + a smaller filter afterwards. The original cross product suggested by my answer was extremely memory inefficient at scale.**

This is a fascinating question! I like your idea to use the apply function to tackle this problem, but passing back a DataFrame to be stored in a series might not be the easiest way to do this. I imagine it would make evaluating the result a real pain.

We should use a merge of the DataFrame and itself to get records next to themselves in a way that is conducive to this comparison.

### My Suggestion

1. Perform a merge of the source data with itself.

   ```
   half_matched_data = data.merge(data, on=["CIPCODE_group", "type"])
   ```

   This will match all rows in your `data` DataFrame with every other row that shares a CIPCODE_group and type. Note that this automatically takes care of two of the filters you were applying.
2. Then we can perform the rest of the filtering that you did in your function but within the merged DataFrame. We only need to do the `!=` operations here since the `==` operations were handled in the merge.

   *Note: columns with the _x suffix will be from the left DataFrame and columns with the _y suffix will be from the right.*

   ```
   similar_programs = half_matched_data[
       (half_matched_data["CIPCODE_decimal_x"] != half_matched_data["CIPCODE_decimal_y"])
       & (half_matched_data["UNITID_x"] != half_matched_data["UNITID_y"])
   ]
   ```

   It doesn't matter if we use _x or _y on either side, just the result will be the same either way since this is a symmetrical operation.
3. Finally, we can extract all of the unique rows from the _x set of columns, and I believe the _y columns associated with each of those unique combinations are what you are looking for.

   *Note: there will be no CIPCODE_group_x or type_x (or their _y counterparts) since we merged these columns and they **must** be the same for both entries in the row. Just treat those columns as belonging to both matched programs.*

   Of course the column names are a little off now, but that just requires a little renaming to fix. Here is a quick way I thought of to return the _x columns to the original names if you want to do that:

   ```
   left_columns = left_columns = [x + '_x' for x in data.columns]
   rename_map = dict(zip(left_columns, data.columns))
   similar_programs.rename(columns=rename_map, inplace=True)
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I did the cross join, It gave me MemoryError: Unable to allocate 487. GiB for an array with shape (65426477796,) and data type int64

Comment: Is your original DataFrame significantly larger than the sample one? (from the error you provided it looks like it's 255786 rows long). I would suggest we try omitting the string info in institution_name and program_name since it is not needed and uses a large amount of memory. I'll edit my answer to include this change!

Comment: @analyst92 You don't need to go full `cross`, you could use `on=['CIPCODE_group', 'type']` and `how='left'` instead. That includes part of the requirements into the `.merge` and as such makes the result smaller.

Comment: @Timus if I use "crossed_data = data.merge(data,on=['CIPCODE_group', 'type'], how='left')" then I get the following error: KeyError: 'CIPCODE_group_x'

Comment: Timus is right. That error you are getting is a leftover error from the code I gave you to execute. Try reloading your dataframe from source. That should clear the renamed columns.

Comment: @analyst92 Sure, the columns you merge `on` don't get suffixes because they are unique now. You have to adjust the following accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what I have to adjust

Comment: @telianer should I remove suffixes now that I am using left join? by the way how did suffixes get automatically attached anyway?!

Comment: @analyst92 The suffixes are produced by the `.merge` to avoid duplicate column names. In `similar_programs = crossed_data[...]` you need to remove the conditions that are related to `CIPCODE_group` and `type`  (they are obsolete now). Additionally, I think the condition `& (crossed_data["CIPCODE_decimal_x"] != crossed_data["CIPCODE_group_y"])` should rather be `& (crossed_data["CIPCODE_decimal_x"] != crossed_data["CIPCODE_decimal_y"])`?

Comment: @Timus I made those changes, now it is saying " MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.62 GiB for an array with shape (2, 175531492) and data type int64
 "

Comment: @analyst92 I updated the answer to cover this new situation comprehensively. Please re-read it and reload your data before applying the transformations suggested therein.

Comment: @telianer I tried the updated solution, now it is saying "MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.31 GiB for an array with shape (175531492,) and data type int64
"

Comment: @telianer, also Timus suggested to use a left join, and you have updated to an inner join it seems

Comment: @analyst92 I think it makes more sense to do an inner join here. I can't think of a situation where left join does anything since the two DataFrames are identical. `left` as an option only matters if there are items in the left DataFrame that are not in the right one. As an aside, you accepted the answer. Is it working now?

Comment: @telianer when I do the merge, it gives an error " MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.31 GiB for an array with shape (175531492,) and data type int64
 "

Comment: @telianer I accepted the answer because it worked for the small data sample I provided, and I wanted to appreciate your help! May you have a happy and blessed life.

Comment: @telianer I only need to generate matching programs for one particular university, so instead of merging the entire duplicated dataframe, how about I merge only those rows which belong to the university (UNITID) I am interested in?

Comment: That could work! I imagine that would solve your problem. I would also recommend removing the `institution_name` and `program_name` before doing the merge as well. They aren't relevant to the filter and they will take up a lot of space in memory. Something like `minimized_data = data[["UNITID", "type", "CIPCODE_group", "CIPCODE_decimal"]]`. Then when you do the merge into `half_matched_data` define it as `minimized_data.merge(minimized_data, on=["CIPCODE_group", "type"])`. The rest of the code can remain the same. If you find you want to see those names later you can always re-merge them in.

Comment: @telianer best wishes, may you live a blessed life